# How to partition to get the rows where a value goes from non NULL to NULL

Tags: null, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partitioning, lag

I have a table as follows where the ATTRIBUTES column contains a json of values.

| ID | ORDER | ATTRIBUTES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | {shape: 'square', size: 'small', length: 14} |
| 12 | 41 | {size: 'small', length: 14} |
| 12 | 22 | {shape: 'square', size: 'large', length: 14} |
| 99 | 42 | {size: 'small', length: 14} |
| 14 | 33 | {shape: 'circle', size: 'small', length: 5} |
| 14 | 58 | {size: 'small', length: 15} |
| 29 | 16 | NULL |

I'm trying to have a query that gets the rows where ATTRIBUTES:shape goes FROM having a value TO being NULL based on ORDER ascending. So for example my resulting table would be

| ID | ORDER | ATTRIBUTES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 41 | {size: 'small', length: 14} |
| 14 | 58 | {size: 'small', length: 15} |

where ID 99 is not included since there was no other record with that ID that had a non NULL shape value (so it didn't go from non NULL to NULL, it was originally just NULL) and ID 29 isn't included since the entire field for that column is NULL.

I tried doing:

```
SELECT *, 
       lag(ATTRIBUTES:shape, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID
       ORDER BY ORDER) AS NULL_SHAPE

FROM MY_TABLE;
```

However I am not able to identify where the ATTRIBUTES:shape becomes NULL from the previous row, is there a way I can specify this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
Functions used:
[QUALIFY()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html)
[LAG()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html)

```
with cte as (
select 12 id, 34 order_id, parse_json('{shape: "square", size: "small", length: 14}') attributes union all
select 12 id, 41 order_id, parse_json('{size: "small", length: 14}') attributes union all
select 12 id, 22 order_id, parse_json('{shape: "square", size: "large", length: 14}') attributes union all
select 99 id, 42 order_id, parse_json('{size: "small", length: 14}') attributes union all
select 14 id, 33 order_id, parse_json('{shape: "circle", size: "small", length: 5}') attributes union all
select 14 id, 58 order_id, parse_json('{size: "small", length: 15}') attributes union all
select 29 id, 16 order_id, NULL attributes)

select 
    *  
from 
    cte  
qualify 
    lag(attributes:shape::string)over(partition by ID order by order_id asc) is not null 
    and attributes:shape::string is null;
```